# CSS3 HTML5 panorama viewer

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I need your help for an university project.
I want to achieve the same result that you can see [on this page](http://musee.louvre.fr/visite-louvre/index.html?defaultView=entresol.s489.p01&lang=ENG).

I need to build a div with a panoramic image inside, that the user can navigate with the mouse controls and when an artwork is hovered/clicked, some informations about it pop out.

I have searched the web and there are a lot of plugins that should work well, but they don't give me the chance to implement the hover/click event to show the informations I want.

Some tutorials/suggestions about my problem? Do you think that [this method](https://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/vr.php) could be a solution?

Thank you all!

Comment: Making this cross-browser compatible will probably make you lose all your hair.

Comment: And if I restrict the choice on Chrome or Firefox would be better?

Comment: Yes. IE10 (and maybe 9) would be possible as well. The main problem, with a lot of these cases, is IE 8 and less (and very old other browsers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is, the solution I've been looking for!

http://www.openstudio.fr/jQuery-virtual-tour,67.html?lang=fr

Hope it helps anybody who has encountered the same problem!

Comment: Getting a 404 from that page, but I'm looking for something similar--would love to see what you ended up making.

Comment: You can see the result here: http://www.abacond.com/progettoUni/apachot-jquery-virtual-tour-8dea9d1/demos/index.html the site changed completely, I think they don't have that code anymore :(